# Apache - Self assigned SSL Help

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, xampp, ssl-certificate

How would I self assign a SSL Cert on Apache (XAMPP) on a Windows 2003 server? I have researched and the farest I got was a broken SSL Cert with "Common name" problem.

Post your guide or links here,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in development and using localhost, the common name of your ssl certificate should be `localhost`. If you are using a machine that uses dns (or the hosts file) you should use that host name as the certificate common name (cn). E.g. if you are using `www.mydomain.com` you should create a certificate with that name. You can also create a certificate with the name `*.mydomain.com` that you should be able to use on all subdomains of `mydomain.com`. You may want to read [this tuturial](http://www.neilstuff.com/apache/apache2-ssl-windows.htm) on the subject.

Comment: Basically my VPS is on localhost, I link my subdomain using a "A-Record" to my VPS. I want the SSL to be on my sub domain. What do I do?

Comment: If you are going to be using this certificate in any kind of production environment you might aswell just go and buy one (noone but yourself will ever trust a self issued certificate). It sounds like you are having trouble generating a valid one, so I suggest you get a trial from http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/free-ssl-certificate.html

Comment: Remember to get one that mathces your A-record

Comment: What do you mean they wont trust? Also, matching the A-record?

Comment: I mean that a computer chooses to trust a certificate based on its certification path. All certificates (except root certificates) are issued by another certificate (the root, or intermediate root certificate). When you point your browser to a https site, your browser will check which root certificate issued the SSL certificate and check if this root certificate is trusted. You can see which root certificates are trusted on your machine by opening the certificates mmc snap in. If the ssl certificates issuer is not trusted the browser will warn you not to visit the website.

Comment: The thing with the matching a-record is what I explained above in the answer. If you have an a-record for www.yourdomain.com pointing the ip of your vps, the ssl certificate's name MUST be www.yourdomain.com, otherwise it will not work.